# Azure Functions in NodeJS, triggers are not available after publish

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

When running "func start" functions are available, but not after publish.

If I run "func azure functionapp publish functiontest" there is no function deployed.

```
func azure functionapp publish functiontest                    
Getting site publishing info...
[2023-11-17T20:57:57.684Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Uploading package...
Uploading 28.18 MB [##############################################################################]
Upload completed successfully.
Deployment completed successfully.
[2023-11-17T21:00:04.675Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in functiontest
```

I have following package.json

```
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
```

Dependency that I am using in package.json:
"@azure/functions": "^4.0.1",

```
import {app} from "@azure/functions";

app.post('myendpoint', { route: 'test/myendpoint', handler: myHandler });
```

I have methods in index.ts.
After `npx tsc` dist/index.js is created and other js files.

Comment: Can you share your code in the question?

Comment: I have tried this [sample](https://i.imgur.com/azXbGYx.png) code and tried publishing the function in the function app with [this](https://i.imgur.com/ajTUoUC.png) command and it worked.

Comment: May I know your Trigger code or Can you try this code with Function JS v4 model

Comment: @DasariKamali I added more details

I have following package.json
```
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
```

Dependency that I am using in package.json:  
        "@azure/functions": "^4.0.1",



app.post('myendpoint', { route: 'test/myendpoint', handler: myHandler });

I have methods in index.ts. After npx tsc dist/index.js is created and other js files.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your code as was able to Deploy the JS HTTP Trigger Function with **`func azure functionapp publish funcappname`**
publish command:-

**Code :**

```js
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";

const myHandler: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.body && req.body.name) {
        context.res = {
            body: `Hello, ${req.body.name}! This is an Azure Functions HTTP trigger.`,
        };
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name in the request body.",
        };
    }
};
export default myHandler;
```

**Command:-**

```bash
func azure functionapp publish funcappname
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Output in Postman :**

[image]

The Function Deployed and triggers successfully in the Function app:-

[image]

Comment: Issue is, that I am migrating already existing project to Azure Functions, I am not creating it from scratch. There are few endpoints, but there is a lot of code and libraries. So I am looking for way how to debug it, why it displays functions locally but not after deployment.Its basically not deploying functions, code looks like invalid after deployment.